# Apply Fade In and Fade Out to mp3 without re-encoding

Tags: linux, command-line, mp3, editing

Since some time i am fighting with how to apply `Fade In` and `Fade Out` effects to mp3. The problem lies in the fact that it needs to happen on linux server as invoked process (command line). The other problem is that it cannot be tool like `FFmpeg` due to decoding and encoding cycle, which causes loss of quality.

I already found a way of how to cut desired part of mp3 without `re-encode` and i am using `mp3splt` for it.

Example of command:

```
mp3splt test.mp3 01.33.65 05.04.38 -o out
```

I was reading documentation but i havent found possibility to apply fade in/out using `mp3splt`, someone suggested other piece of software called `mp3gain` but it also doesnt seem to have this possibility.

So the question is, is it possible to grab my trimmed track and using `command line` apply `fade in` and `fade out` (in desired duration, for example 3 seconds in and 3 seconds out) without `decode/encode` cycle (aka loss of quality), if so which software can do that?

Comment: You can't, as fading in/out means there will be changes in volume (hence the signal). Although if it is done carefully enough, it *might* be possible to only re-encode the head and tail that are involved. (Obviously the approach is to cut the encoded stream into three segments and concatenate the middle one back with the processed head and tail.)

Comment: hmmm, i found a tool https://mpesch3.de/ called `mp3DirectCut` that is advertised as able to trim and fade without `re-encode`so somehow it seems possible, ofc i cannot use it since its windows software with interface, while i am working with linux  and command line only. But maybe there is alternative / equivalent doing similar things

Comment: Well, as I said, if you do not count the fading part, it is *possible* to do it losslessly.